# Rails Model Variable and Associated Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, associations, model-associations

Seemingly simple problem here but I can't wrap my head around why it's doing this. I have a `Post` and `Author` model. I'm using `has_many_and_belongs_to` association between the two models.

When in `rails console`, I can type `Post.find(2).authors` and it will properly list all the authors that belong to that certain post. *But* when I type:

```
my_post = Post.find(2)
my_post.authors
```

it returns an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `authors' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fddb0126b60>
```

The interesting thing I noted was that `Post.find(2).authors` returned:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
```

While my_post returned:

```
ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Does this have an effect on how I can call associated models? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace and your models.  What you've posted should work

Comment: Are you sure you're doing `my_post = Post.find(2)`. Sounds like you're doing `my_post = Post.where(id: 2)`, which would return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. To get the actual `Post` object you can do: `my_post.first` and to get the authors: `my_post.first.authors`.

Comment: Thank you @Mischa That was the problem. I don't understand why a relation can't take the same method calls that the association can? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: `Post.find(2)` returns a `Post` object on which you can call `authors`. `Post.where(...)` returns a collection on which you cannot call `authors`. You have to call `first` first to get the `Post` object. I don't understand your remark of relation vs association. It's a question of `Post` object vs a collection of objects.

Comment: Ah I get it now, I was interpreting it incorrectly. What you explained makes sense, thank you.